# How to dinstinctly document possible REST actions in ViewSet docstring?

Tags: django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-yasg

The DRF [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/) mention this:

> Note that when using viewsets the basic docstring is used for all
>   generated views. To provide descriptions for each view, such as for
>   the the list and retrieve views, use docstring sections as described
>   in Schemas as documentation: Examples.

But the link is bad, and the similar link, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/, doesn't mention these "sections."

How do I *distinctly* document my different possible REST actions within my single Viewset when it is composed like,

```
class ViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,                                            
              mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,                                        
              mixins.CreateModelMixin,                                          
              mixins.UpdateModelMixin,                                        
              ):
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I came here from Google after spending ages tracking this down. There is indeed a special formatting of the docstring to document individual methods for ViewSets.

The relevant example must have been removed from the documentation at some point but I was able to track this down in the source. It is handled by the function `get_description` in https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/schemas/coreapi.py

The docstring format is based on the action names (if view.action is defined):

```
"""
General ViewSet description

list: List somethings

retrieve: Retrieve something

update: Update something

create: Create something

partial_update: Patch something

destroy: Delete something
"""
```

If view.action is not defined, it falls back to the method name: `get`, `put`, `patch`, `delete`.

Each new section begins with a lower case HTTP method name followed by colon.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question.

Comment: Wow, after searching for a while I was convinced there wasn't a simple way to do this without messing with schemas. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me with `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`.

Comment: It's work but only descriptions on each method, string "General ViewSet description" not present in each method description.

Answer (score 8):

Each mixin have specific method like `mixins.ListModelMixin` use `list` method. So you can specify distinctly documentation like this;

```py
    class ViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,                                            
                  mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,                                        
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,                                          
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,):
        queryset = Model.objects.all()
        serializer_class = Serializer
        ...


        def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            """ 
            This endpoints returns list of objects...
            """
            return super(ViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and if you don't have any specific logic then call the `super()` method.

- `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` use `retrieve`
- `mixins.CreateModelMixin` use `create` and
- `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` use `update` methods.

Comment: Thank you, I was imagining some kind of special formatting in the docstring of the class.